# Why can't this code be run by the observer in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

When I run code that looks like this:

```
ask an-agent [set a-field (turtle-set n-values <number> [<reporter>])
```

I get this run-time error message

```
this code can't be run by a turtle, only the observer
error while an-agent running SET
```

But when I write it like this:

```
let a-value (turtle-set n-values <number> [<reporter>])
ask an-agent [set a-field a-value]
```

everything works as expected.

Why does the second version work but not the first?

Thanks.

Comment: That code, as you've written, should be fine. My guess it's something in the reporter passed to `n-values` that is causing the problem. Would you mind posting the full code for that line?

Comment: To clarify- is `field` in your working example the same as `a-field` in your first example?

Comment: Both should be a-field. It's been edited above.

Comment: Here is the reporter: `[path-with-route shuffle nodes-list]`, where `nodes-list` is a local variable in the same procedure, and  `path-with-route` looks like this. 
                                                                                                                   
`to-report path-with-route [a-route]`
  `let a-path nobody`
  `create-paths 1 [`
    `set hidden? true`
    `set path-route a-route`
    `set path-length length-of-route a-route`
    `set a-path self`
  `]`
  `report a-path
end`   (Sorry I can't format it in a comment.)

Comment: Only the observer can `create`.  E.g., try entering the following at the command line: `crt 1 ask turtle 0 [crt 1]`.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain it.  Do you know why that restriction exists? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: In addition, one can: `ask a-breed1 [hatch 1 [set breed breed2]]`, which effectively lets breed1 create a breed2.

Comment: I haven't seen documentation beyond the [dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/create-turtles.html) specifying the `create` primitive as being observer-only, but my two cents would be that the restriction is not in place to prohibit breeds begetting other breeds (easy to do, as you've shown), but because there is a difference between `creat`ing blank turtles/breeds at xy (0,0) and `hatch`ing turtles that inherit variable values from their parents.

Comment: re "Is it documented anywhere", every primitive in the NetLogo Dictionary is marked with little icons showing whether it's an observer, turtle, patch, or link primitive (or some combination).

Comment: @Seth Tisue, Do you know the reason for this constraint? As I pointed out above, it's possible to do a work-around.

Comment: it goes back to StarLogoT, where the observer was implemented completely differently from turtles and it wasn't easy to let turtles just do anything (turtle stuff had to be written in assembly language). the restriction was carried over to NetLogo before I joined the project, perhaps without really questioning it, and has been in place ever since. the idea of lifting it has certainly come up from time to time, but I don't recall if we ever seriously discussed it.